# Consider the operator $T:l^2\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by:

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$$T(\{a_k\})=\sum_1^\infty 2a_k\mathbb{1}_{\big[\frac{k}{4},\frac{k+1}{4}\big)}(x)$$
Show that $T$ is a linear isometry. It is a linear ishomorphism?

Don't know how to start.

Comment: So it's a function of the sequence $\{a_k\}$?

Comment: Yes, I assume, but can't understand very well because it's from $l^2$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: How to start is always with definitions. Write out the definition of an isometry. Write out the definition of an isomorphism. Think for a while and if you're still stuck, come back. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\|T(\left\{a_k\right\})\|_{L^2}^2= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k/4}^{(k+1)/4}4a_k^2 dx= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}\cdot 4a_k^2=\|\left\{a_k\right\}\|_{\ell^2}^2$$
So it is an isometry. It is non surjective, because $T(\left\{a_k\right\})$ is always a function which is constant on intervals of the form $\left[\frac{k}{4},\frac{k+1}{4}\right]$, and thus a function like $f(x)=e^{-x^2}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ cannot be image of any $\left\{a_k\right\}$. Even more simply, if $\ell^2=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, we have $T(\left\{a_k\right\})(x)=0$ for all $x<0$, therefore any $L^2$ function which is non-zero on a positive measure subset of $(-\infty,0]$ cannot be in the range of $T$.

Therefore, it is not an isomorphism.

Comment: In this case isometry implies that the norms are equals, right? So you calculated $||T(\{a_k\})||_{L^2}^2$ and it's equal to $||\{a_k\}||_{L^2}^2$ $\forall k$, so it's an isometry, right?

Comment: A linear operator $T$ is an isometry iff $\|Tu\|=\|u\|$ for all $u$. Do you know a different definition?

Comment: No, but I'm new in functional analysis and I still can't remember all stuff together. Thanks, it was a very easy solution applying only the definition.

Comment: You're welcome. Also remember that for an isometry $T$ the following are equivalent: $(1)$ $T$ is an isomorphism; $(2)$ $T$ is surjective; $(3)$ the range of $T$ is dense.